# @media in mixin (lessphp)

Tags: css, less, mixins, lessphp

I would like to make own mixin wtih mediaqueries like this.

```
@maxWidth: 1170px;

.breakpoint(@maxWidth) {
  @media screen and (max-width: @maxWidth) {
    @content;
   }
 }
```

But @media in mixin doesn't work. Support it lessphp or not? If not, how can I fix it?

P.S. I don't want to make a lot of copies of this rule (@media screen and (max-width: @maxWidth)) in my all .less files.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, Less does not have magic `@content` directive - mixins parameters incl. rules [should be passed explicitly](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature). Though `lessphp` is too outdated compiler that does not support too many today's features, so you're rather trapped with limited Less dialect or need to consider more up-to-date alternatives like `less.php`.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to remove all files related with lessphp from my WordPress theme and after a long search I supposed that with SCSS it will be easier and better to make cool features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider use variables for your needed breakpoints an example:

```
@maxWidth: ~"screen and (max-width: 1170px)";

@media @maxWidth {
   color: red;
 }
```

An example: http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40maxWidth%3A%20~%5C%22screen%20and%20(max-width%3A%201170px)%5C%22%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40media%20%40maxWidth%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20color%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%7D%22%7D

Comment: thanks it's work, but I want make **one mixin with inner @media**, and use this mixin in all files, I assume that this is  impossible -  one mixin with **@media** for all files with less